# Persist Many to Many relationship in different steps

Tags: php, symfony, web, doctrine-orm

Hi I try to solve this problem now for days. But I don't get it so I hope you can help me.

I have the entity Worker and it's in a many to many relation ship with the Task entity.
Now I don't want my user to do all input at one time. At first the user should enter his details and if they are valid he can choose his tasks.

So I added three methods to the standard generated code and change the url path in the *createAction()*.

But if I press the submit button in my AddTaskType form there is nothing persisted to the database.

I hope you have suggestions for this problem.

```
//Worker Entity
namespace DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Workers")
 */
class Worker {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $lastName;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $tel;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    protected $email;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $organisation;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Range(min=6, minMessage="Du musst mindestens 6 Jahre Alt sein um bei uns helfen zu können.")
     */
    protected $age;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Task", inversedBy="workers")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="workers_tasks")
     */
    protected $tasks;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Time", inversedBy="workers")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="workers_times")
     */
    protected $times;
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->tasks = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection ();
        $this->times = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection ();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name          
     * @return Worker
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastName
     *
     * @param string $lastName          
     * @return Worker
     */
    public function setLastName($lastName) {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastName() {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Set tel
     *
     * @param string $tel           
     * @return Worker
     */
    public function setTel($tel) {
        $this->tel = $tel;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tel
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTel() {
        return $this->tel;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email         
     * @return Worker
     */
    public function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set organisation
     *
     * @param string $organisation          
     * @return Worker
     */
    public function setOrganisation($organisation) {
        $this->organisation = $organisation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get organisation
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOrganisation() {
        return $this->organisation;
    }

    /**
     * Set age
     *
     * @param integer $age          
     * @return Worker
     */
    public function setAge($age) {
        $this->age = $age;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get age
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getAge() {
        return $this->age;
    }

    /**
     * Add tasks
     *
     * @param \DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity\Task $tasks         
     * @return Worker
     */
    public function addTask(\DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity\Task $task) {
        $task->addWorker ( $this );
        $this->tasks [] = $task;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove tasks
     *
     * @param \DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity\Task $tasks         
     */
    public function removeTask(\DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity\Task $tasks) {
        $this->tasks->removeElement ( $tasks );
    }

    /**
     * Get tasks
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getTasks() {
        return $this->tasks;
    }

    /**
     * Add times
     *
     * @param \DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity\Time $times         
     * @return Worker
     */
    public function addTime(\DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity\Time $time) {
        $time->addWorker ( $this );
        $this->times [] = $time;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove times
     *
     * @param \DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity\Time $times         
     */
    public function removeTime(\DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity\Time $times) {
        $this->times->removeElement ( $times );
    }

    /**
     * Get times
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getTimes() {
        return $this->times;
    }
}

//TaskEntity
namespace DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Tasks")
 */
class Task {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Time", mappedBy="tasks")
     */
    protected $times;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Worker", mappedBy="tasks")
     */
    protected $workers;
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->times = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection ();
        $this->workers = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection ();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name          
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description           
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setDescription($description) {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Add times
     *
     * @param \DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity\Time $times         
     * @return Task
     */
    public function addTime(\DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity\Time $time) {
        $this->times [] = $time;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove times
     *
     * @param \DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity\Time $times         
     */
    public function removeTime(\DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity\Time $times) {
        $this->times->removeElement ( $times );
    }

    /**
     * Get times
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getTimes() {
        return $this->times;
    }

    /**
     * Add workers
     *
     * @param \DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity\Worker $workers         
     * @return Task
     */
    public function addWorker(\DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity\Worker $worker) {
        $this->workers [] = $worker;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove workers
     *
     * @param \DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity\Worker $workers         
     */
    public function removeWorker(\DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity\Worker $workers) {
        $this->workers->removeElement ( $workers );
    }

    /**
     * Get workers
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getWorkers() {
        return $this->workers;
    }
}
```

**The added methods**

```
//WorkerController.php
/**
     * Add task to a Worker
     *
     * @Route("/", name="task_add")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Template("DLRGHelferBundle:Task:add.html.twig")
     */
    public function addTask(Request $request, $id) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine ()->getManager ();

        $entity = $em->getRepository ( 'DLRGHelferBundle:Worker' )->find ( $id );

        if (! $entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException ( 'Unable to find Worker entity.' );
        }

        $form = $this->createAddTaskForm ( $entity );
        $form->handleRequest ( $request );

        if ($form->isValid ()) {

            $formData = $form->get ( 'tasks' )->getData ();

            foreach ( $formData as $task ) {
                $entity->addTask ( $task );
            }

            $em->persist ( $entity );
            $em->flush ();

            return $this->redirect ( $this->generateUrl ( 'worker_show', array (
                    'id' => $entity->getId () 
            ) ) );
        }

        return array (
                'entity' => $entity,
                'form' => $form->createView () 
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to add a Task to Worker entity.
     *
     * @param Worker $entity
     *          The entity
     *          
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createAddTaskForm(Worker $entity) {
        $form = $this->createForm ( new AddTaskType (), $entity, array (
                'action' => $this->generateUrl ( 'task_add', array (
                        'id' => $entity->getId () 
                ) ),
                'method' => 'POST' 
        ) );

        $form->add ( 'submit', 'submit', array (
                'label' => 'Zeiten' 
        ) );

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new Worker entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new/{id}/addTask", name="worker_task")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function addAction($id) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine ()->getManager ();

        $entity = $em->getRepository ( 'DLRGHelferBundle:Worker' )->find ( $id );

        if (! $entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException ( 'Unable to find Worker entity.' );
        }

        $form = $this->createAddTaskForm ( $entity );

        return array (
                'entity' => $entity,
                'form' => $form->createView () 
        );
    }
```

My AddTaskType looks like this:

```
namespace DLRG\HelferBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use DLRG\HelferBundle\Controller\HelferController;

class AddTaskType extends AbstractType {
    /**
     *
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder         
     * @param array $options            
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add ( 'tasks', 'entity', array (
                'class' => 'DLRGHelferBundle:Task',
                'property' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true 
        ) );
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver            
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults ( array (
                'data_class' => 'DLRG\HelferBundle\Entity\Worker' 
        ) );
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'dlrg_helferbundle_addTask';
    }
}
```

Comment: The Task should have it's own entity. You need to hydrate the form results into Task entities and then add those entities, then persist both entities.

Comment: The Task has its own entity and the User can't add task. He only should choose some.

Comment: It's almost guaranteed that you are trying to supply something OTHER than an entity to ->addTask()

Comment: As I understand, the addTask Method add a Task to my Worker. When I now persist the Worker Entity it automaticly should persist the changes to my task_workers table. But this doesn't happen.